# Import cells from Excel using Smartsheet

Tags: python, excel, smartsheet-api

I have been trying to import a few cells from an Excel file into Smartsheet through the API, but don't know what I keep getting wrong.

```
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')
cell_range = sheet['A8':'G88']
access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
sheet_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ss = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)
ss.errors_as_exceptions(True)
sheet = ss.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)
row_id= "1"
single_row = ss.Sheets.get_row(sheet_id, row_id)
destination_cell = single_row.get_column(DST_COLUMN_ID)
destination_cell.value = cell_range
single_row.set_column(destination_cell.column_id, destination_cell)
ss.Sheets.update_rows(sheet_id, row_id)
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start small and work your way up.

Issues that I can see:

- get_row needs a row Id as returned from the API. (Not a row number)
- cell.value should be a string or number, not a range
- update_rows needs a row object, not id

Take a look at this sample for code that updates cell values: https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/python-read-write-sheet